# How do you draw a border around banners that aren't off-center?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Does anyone know how I can draw a thin border around my Illustrator artboards where the border/stroke is equal on all sides after the export? What happens to me is if I have a 100px x 100px artboard, when exported it will be 1px on top, .5px on the sides and 1px on the bottom even though it is on the edge, set to inside and the correct dimensions.

Comment: Reading your question I guess there are banners of different widths, so the thickness of the border varies. Haven't you thought about leaving it without border and add a CSS border as it's explained [here](http://themes.typepad.com/guide/2011/12/banner-border.html)?

Comment: I tested here (Illustrator CC 2015) and everything is fine.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using the latest version of Illustrator CC 2018 (22.1).

Comment: The banners are not for my website so I can't use CSS. And the dimensions here was just an example. I usually make 5 banners at once with different art board dimensions and every time an exact outline on the edges are never equal meaning they get cut off by half a pixel, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that you had just created the banner/border with the incorrect size.

- Try using **Smart Guides** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>)
- Create the square by clicking and manually entering in the **W**x**H** value instead of *Click+Drag* to make it

  ---

When exporting you can **untick** the *Clip to Artboard* and that will export the image as far (or near) as the artwork spreads (but if it isn't a square, this may mess up your final project).

If you want to put a border around and clip to artboard, you just have to change the alignment of the stroke.

- Open the stroke panel and choose from one of the **Align Stroke** options:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!!! I really just needed to untick the clip to artboard and that all saved everything and kept the border inside. Perfect solution. Thanks.